# Can you install Android TV onto other devices?

Tags: android-tv, ouya

I was wondering if it is possible to install Android TV on either the GameStick, Ouya, Mad Catz M.O.J.O, or any other device like that in order to breathe new life into these devices.

Comment: Or old smartphones, etc.